# What is the difference between "I am done with you" and "We are through"?

Tags: meaning

What is the difference between "I am done with you" and "We are through" ?

I heard them in some soaps and I thought that might have same meaning in the first place, but I am asking because just in case if they have any little difference.

Comment: Have you done any research on these phrases? For instance, [here](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/have+done+with+you) or [here](http://www.wordreference.com/definition/done) or [here](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/were-through-were-over.2307175/)? Sometimes a little searching is worth the effort!

Comment: It would be helpful if you include what _you_ know about them, so that others can point out any differences you have missed.

Comment: I have done so many researches on them with my own dictionary and some kind of internet dictionary..Since I am EFL student and have no tutor either there are so many phrases like them that I could get the meaning accurately on my own, and that is why I am using this site. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase "I am done with you" signifies more of a personal decision; it means that the person speaking has decided to no longer have anything to do with the other, so it signifies the end of the speaker's commitment to the relationship.

"We are through" refers more to the relationship itself being finished than to the speaker's desire for it to be over.

Comment: Welcome to ELL. For future reference, answers should contain evidence, like dictionary entries, whenever possible. - [From Review](http://ell.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/44576).

Comment: I dunno. I've used, I mean people use *we're through* to announce one's personal decision/desire  to bring about the end of a relationship.

Comment: Also note that neither phrase has to denote the ending of a relationship, or any negative emotion.    My dentist might say 'Ok, we're through!' at the end of a treatment session.   It would denote a successful conclusion and we would part on friendly terms.